# TWIML Whisper Announce

Tags: twilio

I'm using a simple twiml to to forward and record a call.  What I would like to do is say a message to the callee to say this is a potential sales call, and it may be recorded.  I don't want the caller to hear it.

Here's my current twiml.

`<Response>
    <Dial record="true">18885551212</Dial>
</Response>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You'll need to use the `<Number>` noun within the `<Dial>` verb.  Number has a parameter named *url* that lets you give Twilio a URL that returns TwiML to play to the dialed party before they are connected.

There is a How To that walks you through creating a Whisper:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/ivrs-call-screening-and-recording

Hope that helps.